# About collective nouns

Tags: collective-nouns

A family lives in Yorkshire, and the family are eating lunch.

Can I say that a family [who are] eating lunch lives in Yorkshire?

I want to unite a plural verb and a singular verb in one clause. But I think it’s not a case.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132255/discussion-on-question-by-user284747-about-collective-nouns).